# How do I call a function with a variable number of parameters?

Tags: c, function, variadic-functions, argument-passing

How do I call `execlp()` with a variable number of arguments for different processes?

Comment: Why not just use `execvp` if the number of arguments can vary at runtime?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't know how many arguments you'll need at the time you are writing your code, you want to use execvp(), not execlp():

```
char **args = malloc((argcount + 1) * sizeof(char *));
args[0] = prog_name;
args[1] = arg1;
...
args[argcount] = NULL;

execvp(args[0], args);
```

Answer (score 1):

This answers only the title question

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h)
Covers old and new styles

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void printargs(int arg1, ...) /* print all int type args, finishing with -1 */
{
  va_list ap;
  int i;

  va_start(ap, arg1); 
  for (i = arg1; i != -1; i = va_arg(ap, int))
    printf("%d ", i);
  va_end(ap);
  putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
   printargs(5, 2, 14, 84, 97, 15, 24, 48, -1);
   printargs(84, 51, -1);
   printargs(-1);
   printargs(1, -1);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`execlp()` can be called with variable number or arguments, so just call:

```
int ret;
ret = execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", (char *)0);
ret = execlp("echo", "echo", "hello", "world", (char *)0);
ret = execlp("man", "man", "execlp", (char *)0);
ret = execlp("grep", "grep", "-l", "pattern", "file1", "file2", (char *)0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Execlp already as a variable number of parameters. What do you want to do exactly ?
You can probably a [variadic macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) :

```
#define myfind(...) execlp("find", "find", __VA_ARGS__)
```

This is a rather useless example, but without knowing more precisely what you wanted to do, that's all I could come up with

Comment: That's not the syntax for (standard) C99 variadic macros. Why continue to use it?

Comment: Sorry for this, what is the syntax then ?